# Microsoft Outlook 2013: Error verify VBA project signature

Tags: vba, outlook, certificate, outlook-2013

After a computer reset I wanted to use my VBA Macros for Outlook 2013.

In Outlook I get the error message:

> "An errror occured while attempting to verify the VBA project's signature. Macros will be disabled."

Consequently the VBA editor states:

> "The macros in this project are disabled. [..]"

I have tried:

1. Developer -> Macro Security -> (*) Enable all Macros (not only digitally signed)
2. Define a certificate using

   ```
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\selfcert.exe
   ```

Nothing worked. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found the reason for my problem:

(1) The Certificate `nameofmycert` by selfcert.exe was assigned to my VBA project.

(2) However I didn't assign it to a trusted authority, like seen in: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754841.aspx#BKMK_addlocal

(3) Outlook was set to allow all macros (not only digitally signed). Anyhow it found that my VBA project was certified, but was not sure if the cerification is correct, because of (2). Therefore it deactivated all macros.

(4) In VBA/Tools / Dignital Signature it appeared:

```
Certificate name: [no certificate]
Sign as: nameofmycert
```

The remove-botton was deactivated.

**Solution:**

(1) VBA/Tools / Digital Signature

(2) Click on `Choose ..` and select a cerificate. Then the remove-botton is activated.

(3) Click on `Remove Certificate`

(4) Save VBA project

(5) Restart Outlook

Comment: That's because your project/code used a self-signed certificate. When you move the code on another machine you need to use a certificate from a trusted vendor which can confirm that. Self-signed certificates are used for testing mainly.

Comment: Worth noting that the reason I got into self-signing macros was so I could run with higher security, disabling unsigned macros. After setting macro security thus and starting Outlook as non-admin, I was prompted to trust M$ cert for VBA and to trust my self-signed cert. I did so, and _then_ all was well.

Answer (score 11):

Having come across this just now, this is how I ultimately solved it (none of the other suggestions worked for me):

1. Create a self cert – I called mine “Self Cert” (generated from here in Office 2013 - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\SELFCERT.EXE)
2. Run certmgr.crt from the start menu and copy “Self Cert” from “Personal\Certificates” to the “Trusted Root Certification Authorities\Certificates” folder
3. Open Outlook.exe as Administrator
4. Open VBA (i.e. Developer -> Visual Basic)
5. Open your module containing the VBA code
6. Select Tools -> Digital Signature -> Choose...
7. Select OK to select “Self Cert” (VB then shows the project as being signed with this certificate) then click OK again accept and close the window
8. Click to save the macro in VBA – actually click the save button in VB (*bizarrely it breaks if you don’t expressly save here*)
9. Close VBA
10. Close Outlook, and choose Yes to save the VBA project
11. Restart Outlook.exe again as Administrator
12. Either now, or after you go “Developer -> Visual Basic” again, a window should pop-up prompting you about the newly signed macro – I clicked remember and don’t prompt again
13. Macros should now work! I'm using them as part of an email rule and this now processes perfectly.

I’m not strictly sure you need to run Outlook as an administrator in the above, but it now works without being run as an administrator so I’m happy.

Thanks to this resource for getting this working for me! I've basically just updated, consolidated and expanded on answers given. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/07f0158c-085b-4031-93a1-c9d047cf855c/unable-to-sign-outlook-2010-vbaproject?forum=outlook

Comment: Additionally, I had to copy my macro code, delete the VBA project, close Outlook, delete the OTM file in the  %AppData%\Microsoft\Outlook  folder, reopen Outlook, create a new macro project, paste in the copied code, add the certificate, and voila!

Comment: works perfeclty, now you can change option in Outlook Trust Center to Notifications for digitally signed macros, all other macros disabled.

Comment: For Office 365 `selfcert.exe`  is not creating certificates under `\Personal\Certificates`.  Searching in certificate manager returns no results.  Any thoughts on where I should look?

Comment: Working now: no need to use certificate manager if you remember to do the double save (steps 8 and 10)

Comment: For me it worked after executing step 8) to explicitly click Save in the VBA editor. No need for admin mode, just that explicit Save click. Saying "Yes" to the save the VBA code question when closing Outlook was not enough in my case

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem and the solution here fixed it: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/07f0158c-085b-4031-93a1-c9d047cf855c/unable-to-sign-outlook-2010-vbaproject?forum=outlook.  The thread is long, but the gist of it is you need to manually save your VBA project after signing, and before exiting the VBA editor. Scroll down about 2/3rds of the way to the post by "Diane Poremsky [MVP]".

Comment: This resolve it for me, I had done everything correctly, but I basically had to go "File, Save" from VB Editor. I have a feeling this is related to me already having Macros existing before I started messing with certs, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score -2):

You need to change the Trust Center settings (run all macros, not only digitally signed) or purchase a valid certificate from a trusted authority.

Comment: This is equivalent the option (1), which i have tried. Unfortunatly this solution which seemed to be obvious was not working. Outlook deactivated the macros regardless of this option.

Comment: Did you try to restart Outlook after changing the Trust Center settings?

Comment: Yes. I did even try a windows restart. I'm currently suspecting a bug in Outlook and was hoping that there is a known workaround.

Comment: This is not true. You don't need to purchase a certificate. Self-signed certificates should work fine. I had this same problem and the solution here fixed it: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/07f0158c-085b-4031-93a1-c9d047cf855c/unable-to-sign-outlook-2010-vbaproject?forum=outlook.  The thread is long, but the gist of it is you need to manually save your VBA project after signing, and before exiting the VBA editor. Scroll down about 2/3rds of the way to the post by "Diane Poremsky [MVP]".

Comment: Self-signed certificate is designed to work only on your machines. That's made for testing purposes mainly. There should be a third part which can confirm the code comes from a trusted vendor. See [Digital signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature) for more information.

Comment: It also seems to be different for different versions of outlook. I have never had any problems with certificates until office 2016. The work around at the top of the thread worked for me.