# Microsoft Outlook 2019: Error verify VBA project signature

Tags: vba, outlook, certificate

After moving into a new desktop with Outlook 2019 installed, my VBA Macros wouldn't run. It was failing silently. Finally I triggered this error message:

> An error occured while attempting to verify the VBA project's signature. Macros will be disabled.

And the VBA editor states:

> The macros in this project are disabled…

I tried answers [Microsoft Outlook 2013: Error verify VBA project signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30619881/microsoft-outlook-2013-error-verify-vba-project-signature/48411874), but the information is outdated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30619881/microsoft-outlook-2013-error-verify-vba-project-signature

Answer (score 0):

The advice given by [Signing your own macros with SelfCert.exe](https://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/selfcert.htm) worked fine. I’m not going to duplicate the write-up, which has excellent visual aids. Here’s what I learned in my own words. Maybe this will help you avoid wading through the whole article. (That’s not to say it’s hard to read.)

Here are the steps:

1. Create a self-signed certificate
2. Sign the macro with the certificate
3. Verify your Outlook security settings
4. Run for the first time

Here are more details.

One needs to have a certificate to digitally sign one’s macros. For most of us, that means creating a self-signed certificate, which is probably why you searched for an answer to this problem. Office has a utility to do this. I have the 64-bit version of Office, so I ran `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\SelfCert.exe` (see the article I linked to for other versions).

In the VBA Editor (ALT+F11) where you created the macro, choose:

```
Tools-> Digital Signature…
```

You should see that the current VBA project isn’t signed yet. That’s the problem. Unlike 2013, when you press the Choose… button you’ll get a screen to select the certificate you just created. (Installation was automatic.)

Next navigate:

```
File-> Options-> Trust Center-> Trust Center Settings…-> Macro Settings
```

Ensure this option is selected: Notifications for digitally signed macros, all other macros disabled

Restart Outlook. When you exit, you’ll be prompted to save changes to your VBA project. Choose “Yes”.

When you run your newly-signed macro the first time, you’ll be notified. Select that you’ll always trust the macros or documents from this publisher and you won’t be prompted again.

Comment: Following the article doesn't resolve the error, in fact I started with the article and tested 3x before coming here.

Comment: Nope. Same here - the described process does not work any longer on Windows 10 and Outlook 2016 32-bit. The "notifcation" is the subject error message with no option to work around.